# Processor not running at max speed

Tags: cpu, speed, power-management, intel-core2

My laptop has an Intel Core 2 Duo T9300 which should be running at 2.5GHz, however CPU-Z consistently reports my Core speed at right under 1.6Ghz (8x multiplier and ~200MHz Bus Speed).  Even when I'm doing heavy development work and the processor is running at 100% for extended periods of time the core speed reported by CPU-Z never goes up to 2.5GHz.  My understanding is that this reduction in speed is to save power, but this happens even when I'm plugged into the outlet.

Does anyone know why this is happening or how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does anyone know why this is happening

Its called [SpeedStep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_step)

```
how to fix it?
```

There's nothing to "fix" per-se, as and when the load increases, the frequency will bump up.

Also,

> Under Microsoft Windows XP, SpeedStep
>   support is built into the power
>   management console under the control
>   panel. In Windows XP a user can
>   regulate the processor's speed
>   indirectly by changing power schemes.
>   The "Home/Office Desk" disables
>   SpeedStep, the "Portable/Laptop" power
>   scheme enables SpeedStep, and the "Max
>   Battery" uses SpeedStep to slow the
>   processor to minimal power levels as
>   the battery weakens. The SpeedStep
>   settings for power schemes, either
>   built-in or custom, cannot be modified
>   from the control panel's GUI, but can
>   be modified using the POWERCFG.EXE
>   command-line utility.

Comment: Changing the power scheme to "Home/Office Desk" and restarting took care of the problem.  Thanks!

Comment: @Andrew Hampton Good to hear!

Answer (score 1):

Check your "Power Saving" settings and choose the "performance" option.  And plug your box in.. Most laptops will go into power saving mode automatically when unplugged from wall power.

Comment: Do you mean "Power Options" in the Control Panel?  This is an XP machine.  "Performance" isn't an option on the Power Schemes tab, but the speed reported by CPU-Z didn't change after trying a few of the settings there.

Comment: Your CPU may just be idling itself if it's underused.  Try running a game or archiving your outlook email in the background while checking the speed.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a customer with this problem with an HP-15 machine with Windows 10 installed.  The processor speed was actually throttled back to 25% of rated capacity.  No SpeedStep available in the BIOS.

After several hours of fiddling around, I deleted "Intel Dynamic Platform and Thermal Framework" from "System Devices" and that fixed the problem.  (Note, you cannot delete it from the main "Device Manager" menu...at least I couldn't, but deleting it from the System submenu worked).

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.